# Input Buffer error or something else?

Tags: c++, input, buffer, cin, getch

I have this code which works fine but I cant comprehend the meaning of cin.get(ch) in the for loop. I tested the program after removing it and the first input comes fine but as soon as loop runs for the second time, program does not wait for the user to input "name" and skips automatically to "marks".

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<fstream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main ()
{       clrscr();
int marks;
char name[40];
char ch;
ofstream a("STUDENT.txt",ios::app);
char ans='y';
while(ans=='y'|| ans=='Y')
{   cout<<"\nEnter name of student: " ;
    cin.getline(name,40);
    cout<<"Enter marks of student: ";
    cin>>marks;
    cout<<"Want to enter more? (y/n)";
    cin>>ans;
    cin.get(ch);
    a<<"\n"<<name<<"\n"<<marks;
    }
a.close ();
getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`cin >> ans` only reads a single character from the input. So when the user types <kbd>y Return</kbd>, `y` will be put in `ans`, but the input buffer will still contain the newline. When you go back to the `cin.getline(name, 40)`, this will look like an empty line. `cin.get(ch)` reads the next character, which is that extra newline.

A better way to do it would be to use `cin.getline()` to read the answer to "Want to enter more?" into a string, and then check whether the first character of the string is `y`.